# Setting environment variables for XAMMP

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I'm struggling a bit with getting my environment variables through to my CodeIgniter project. I'm running an XAMMP localhost server for development. I've tried using the `getenv($var);`which half worked, but it's not picking up the variables that I'm exporting in my terminal. I have a feeling that it's picking up the Apache environment rather than my actual local environment.

For instance, if I echo out my $PATH variable in terminal, I get a different output to `echo getenv("PATH");` in my code.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use super global variable instead of getenv() i.e $_SERVER['PATH']

Q: Why does you need that? need for detect env you working (development or production?)

Comment: I will try that, thanks. The company I'm developing for wants certain variables used this way, in case they change domains etc. They can just change environment variables instead of going into the code to change the base_url for example.

Comment: I tried the SERVER super global, it gives me the same results as getenv();

Answer (score 0):

Use base_url() & site_url() like this. It will solve your problem whatever your domain. And remember dont change your config file's `$config['base_url']`

For resource link (images,js,css etc)

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/test.css');?>
// dont use base_url().'/assets/css/test.css' like this
```

and for others links

```
<?php echo site_url('controller/method');?>
```

It will work on any environment even in subdomain  & (change domain name) not effect any code

Comment: I never thought of doing this! Thanks so much, will try it out.